# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Tags: command-line

What is the correct format for if then?
I tried lots of varieties.
Should the format work at the command line when not in a program?

```
$ if [1==2] then echo "y" fi;
> ;
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Comment: All 3 keywords (`if`, `then`, `fi`) should start their own separate lines. Or have semicolon in front of them: `if [ 1 == 2 ]; then echo "y"; fi`. Beside that, spaces around `[`'s arguments are mandatory.

Comment: also see that `[1==2]`  must have space between the `[` , `]` and  the numbers, that is [ 1 -eq 2 ] as bash parser needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if [ 1 == 2 ]; then echo "y" ; fi
```

And better use `-eq`, unless you want to compare 1 and 2 as a strings.

Useful link: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 4):

Nobody explained the error yet.

You entered:

```
if [1==2] then echo "y" fi;
;
```

The first line was perfectly valid syntax as far as the shell was concerned. It is of the form:

```
if cmd args
```

In this case, `cmd` is derived from the expansion of the `[1==2]` glob. `[1==2]` is a globbing pattern that expands to the list of files in the current directory whose name consist of either a `1`, `=` or `2` character.

For instance, if there's a file called `2` in  the current directory, that becomes:

if 2 then echo fi;

That is run the `2` command with 4 arguments: `2`, `then`, `echo` and `fi`, as the first command in the `if` part of an `if/then/elif/else/fi` statement.

The error comes from that second `;` on the second line. You would have had the same error message by entering that `;` alone on the command line. `;` must be used to separate commands, it cannot be used on its own like that.

Answer (score 3):

The correct form of the bash `if` construct is

```
if something; then command; fi
```

The correct form of what you seem to be attempting do do is

```
if [ 2 -eq 2 ]; then echo "y"; fi;
```

Spaces are important in bash.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator doesn't exist in Bash. It's either `-eq` when comparing numbers or `=` when comparing strings.

```sh
if [ 1 -eq 2 ]; then echo 'y'; fi
```

Comment: `==` does exist in bash, it just does string comparison, like `=`. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).